# Number pyramid, can't get numbers to print out to the left

Tags: java, for-loop

I need a full pyramid but I can only get the right side of it. It is suppose to look like this with a example output of 4:

```
    1
   212
  32123
 4321234
```

I'm still new to java for loops so I've tried doing negative increments but that didn't work is there a type of method to print it in reverse?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pyramid {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number 1 to 15");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input1 = input.nextInt();
        if (input1 >= 1 && input1 <=15) {
            for(int column =1; column <input1; column++) {
                for(int row = 1; row < column; row++) {
                    System.out.print(row + " ");
                }
                System.out.print(column);
            System.out.println();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not really printing a pyramid, you are printing a rectangle with numbers and spaces. Maybe this will help you visualize a solution

Comment: Hi Janes, can you please share what the current output looks like. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need more loops, and you work row by row, and not col by col so the outer loop should use `row`.

And the inner loops are for :

- print the spaces
- print the numbers is descending order until 1 (exlude)
- print the numbers is ascending order from 1

```
for(int row = 1; row <= input1; row++) {
    for(int space = 0; space < input1-row; space++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for(int desc = row; desc > 1; desc--) {
        System.out.print(desc);
    }
    for(int asc = 1; asc <= row; asc++) {
        System.out.print(asc);
    }
System.out.println();
}
```